# Fullpage.js: How to change the color of the anchor?

Tags: fullpage.js

i'm wondering if anyone can tell me how to change the anchor colors? Right now those on my test site is showing as grey and I hope you agree that it's kinda drown in the full-screen pics. I need it to be in white.

here's my test site:

www.heartpatrick.com/indexnew.html

Thanks all. :)

Comment: What anchors are you talking about? Proper HTML anchors/links, as in the `<a>` tag (of which I don't see grey)? Unless you're talking about something else entirely. Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: oh it's those horizontal row of dots near the bottom center of the page, that indicates how many items are there. i have a screenshot here: www.heartpatrick.com/screenshot.jpg

Comment: It is all about CSS and HTML. Nothing about fullPage.js...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you're looking for is `#fp-nav ul li a span, .fp-slidesNav ul li a span`. For example, to make them full red:

```
#fp-nav ul li a span, .fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
    background: #F00;
}
```

Feel free to use whatever color you like in place of `#F00`. Place the rule sometime after `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css">` is loaded.

Comment: Remember to use the !important tag just in case it doesn't want to load.